# Is it possible to make wordpress comment box as required field?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

Normally wordpress comment field is not a required field and we can not control that from admin panel. Is it possible to make that required field as name and the email fields?

If it possible how could I do it?

Is it code change or configuration change?

Comment: Well it is required - if you submit the form without entering a comment(text in the textarea), you will see an error message. Do you want to not allow users to submit the form without entering a message?

Comment: @Nikola Ivanov Nikolov Thanks! That is good point.

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov, post that as an answer - [free snap](http://i.stack.imgur.com/j1zVR.png) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is required - if you submit the form without entering a comment(text in the textarea), you will see an error message : [image]